# Overlay image over image with variable height in CSS

Tags: css, image

I have an image (base.jpg) which has the following css:

```
.thumb-image {
padding: 0;
border: none;
margin: 0 auto 5px;
display: block;
width: 205px;
background: #EEE;
color: #8A8989;
border-image: initial;}

<img class="thumb-image" src="base.jpg" alt="" onerror="this.src='thumb.png'">
```

The image height is variable. Is there anyway I can overlay another image (overlay.png which is the red image) on top of base.jpg on the bottom right cornerusing css by adding another class declaration to the above css?

[image]
Many thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need a wrapper div and then absolute position the corner image.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <img src="img/big.jpg" class="big" alt=""/>
    <img src="img/corner.jpg" class="corner" alt=""/>
</div>

#wrap { position: relative; }
.big, .corner { display: block; }
.corner { position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; }
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer for image overlaying over another image, short and sweet! This CSS part: `.big, .corner { display: block; }` is not necessary in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much you can do with just `.thumb-image`. If you modify the HTML somewhat, you can accomplish this fairly easily. I've put up an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/imsky/AsUuh/

This works IE8+ (with doctype), and across all other modern browsers, by using :before and generated content. You can convert it to use no modern features, but that would mean including an extra DIV inside each container. As an aside, :before doesn't work on IMG tags, so this is as minimal of markup as possible.

HTML:

```
<div class="thumb-container">
<div class="thumb-image">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/205/300">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumb-image {
    margin:0 auto 5px;
    width:205px;
    background:#EEE;
    color:#8A8989;
    border-image:initial;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0
}
.thumb-image img {
    border:0;
    display:block;
    width:100%
}
.thumb-container {
    position:relative
}

.thumb-image:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index:1;
    background:url(http://placekitten.com/100)
}
```